# Trouble with the quick start guide

Tags: android, kiosk, kiosk-mode, android-management-api

I'm trying to follow the quick start guide and have gotten this far. This should be a simple step that I don't think I'm messing up.

I'm getting this error:

```
HttpError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-bcfca1a6c4ac> in <module>()
     17     signupUrlName=signup_url['name'],
     18     enterpriseToken=enterprise_token,
---> 19     body={}
     20 ).execute()
     21 

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/googleapiclient/http.py in execute(self, http, num_retries)
    896             callback(resp)
    897         if resp.status >= 300:
--> 898             raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
    899         return self.postproc(resp, content)
    900 

HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://androidmanagement.googleapis.com/v1/enterprises?projectId=ssapptest&signupUrlName=signupUrls%2FCfd59b86982be3c7c&enterpriseToken=EAJmqckwEH8mD3tZnKKqQmCqL_qXuhR15BbAuA1QJP-Sl9EwawDekO-MXBWe7xFzPI8nqynhjQ3o7ympqJpSrIQzaKWPeKLD4R4nqE9BPI1JvkmB9fhE80P4&alt=json returned "domain: "androidenterprise.ApiErrors"
code: "INVALID_COMPLETION_TOKEN"
argument: "Cfd59b86982be3c7c"
debug_info: "code: INVALID_COMPLETION_TOKEN\nhttp status: 400\narguments: [Cfd59b86982be3c7c]\ncause: com.google.wireless.android.vending.enterprise.common.exceptions.InvalidCompletionTokenException: EnterpriseException{httpStatus=400, code=androidenterprise.ApiErrors.INVALID_COMPLETION_TOKEN, arguments=[Cfd59b86982be3c7c]}\n\tat com.google.wireless.android.vending.enterprise.business.LaForgeServiceImpl.completeSignup(LaForgeServiceImpl.java:648)\n\tat com.google.wireless.android.vending.enterprise.actions.mdmapi.EnterpriseActions$CompleteSignupAction.execute(EnterpriseActions.java:222)\n\tat com.google.apps.framework.request.impl.InterceptorInvocation$Rpc.beforeProceed(InterceptorInvocation.java:147)\n\tat com.google.apps.framework.request.impl.InterceptorInvocation.proceed(InterceptorInvocation.java:158)\n\tat com.google.apps.framework.request.impl.RpcDispatcher.proceed(RpcDispatcher.java:136)\n\tat com.google.apps.framework.request.impl.RpcDispatcher.proceed(RpcDispatcher.java:42)\n\tat com.google.apps.framework.request.impl.AbstractDispatcher.doExecuteChain(AbstractDispatcher.java:464)\n\tat com.google.apps.framework.request.impl.AbstractDispatcher.execute(AbstractDispatcher.java:303)\n\tat com.google.apps.framework.request.impl.AbstractDispatcher.executeAsync(AbstractDispatcher.java:226)\n\tat com.google.apps.framework.request.impl.RpcDispatcher.handleRpc(RpcDispatcher.java:126)\n\tat com.google.apps.framework.request.impl.RpcScopedHandlerFactoryImpl.run(RpcScopedHand...
```

I can see that it is an invalid completion token, but I don't understand where that is coming from.

To solve this, I've tried searching Google for it and read over the Android Management API documentation, but I haven't found anything talking about errors with this.

I've laso tried contacting Google Suites tech support hoping they would be able to provide some insight, but they referred me to the Android Enterprise where I wasn't able to find contact information.

Does anyone have any ideas what is causing this or how to fix it?

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

It just started working. The only thing that I can tihnk was happening was that I used my mouse to copy and paste it instead of Ctrl+C.